# I can't call schedule, or the function doesn't start in schedule?

Tags: python, schedule

As you can see that I have created a class then the functions,

In funcion 'Hepsi' I tried the call another function, when I execute 'Hepsi' it works fine, however when I call this function in schedule, it doesn't work, schedule part never work in code.
The result is just says "Process finished with exit code 0".
Any idea?

```py
class main(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        # self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
        self.driver = uc.Chrome()
    
    def TRV_Giris(self):
        # self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[0])
        self.driver.get('https://tr.tradingview.com/')
        self.driver.maximize_window()
    
        try:
            uye_girisi = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/button[1]")))
            uye_girisi.click()
        except:
            print("Arama Kutusu patladı")
        try:
            uye_girisi = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located(
                    (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='overlap-manager-root']/div/span/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div")))
            uye_girisi.click()
        except:
            print("Arama Kutusu patladı")
        try:
            uye_girisi = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                                "//*[@id='overlap-manager-root']/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/span")))
            uye_girisi.click()
        except:
            print("Arama Kutusu patladı")
    
        time.sleep(2)
    
        # self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[1]) #TAB DEĞİŞTİRME
    
        try:
            uye_girisi = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username")))
            uye_girisi.send_keys("sezginsayiliroglu@gmail.com")
            pyautogui.keyDown("tab")
            pyautogui.keyUp("tab")
        except:
            print("email Kutusu patladı")
    
        try:
            uye_girisi = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password")))
            uye_girisi.send_keys("pitonotomasyon22")
            pyautogui.keyDown("enter")
            pyautogui.keyUp("enter")
            time.sleep(2)
            pyautogui.click(x=1684, y=187)
            time.sleep(1)
            pyautogui.keyDown("escape")
            pyautogui.keyUp("escape")
    
        except:
            print("ŞİFRE Kutusu patladı")
    
        self.driver.get('https://tr.tradingview.com/chart')
        time.sleep(2)
        a = 5
    
    def Excel(self,Coinadi,Result,Column,BuySellVal):
        okuExcel = openpyxl.load_workbook("Coin.xlsx")
        Coinadi = okuExcel[Coinadi]
        Coinadi.cell(row=1, column=1, value=Result)
        Coinadi.cell(column=Column, row=Coinadi.max_row + 1, value=BuySellVal)
    
    def AL_SAT_ARA(self,Coinname):
    
        try:
            AramaKutusu = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='header-toolbar-symbol-search']")))
            AramaKutusu.click()
            YaziKutusu = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='overlap-manager-root']/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/input")))
            YaziKutusu.send_keys(Coinname+"USDT")
            YaziKutusu.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            time.sleep(1.5)
            Kontrol_Deger = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='header-toolbar-symbol-search']").text
            while Kontrol_Deger != Coinname + "USDT":
                Kontrol_Deger = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                         "//*[@id='header-toolbar-symbol-search']").text
                time.sleep(0.1)
        except:
            print("ters gitti bişeyler")
    
        okuExcel = openpyxl.load_workbook("Coin.xlsx")
        Coinname = okuExcel[Coinname]
        deger = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/span[2]").text
        class StopLookingForThings(Exception):
            pass
        try:
            im = ImageGrab.grab()
            px = im.load()
            # print(self.okuDeger)
            for h in range(-2468, -2271):
                r = h * -1
                if px(r, 686) == (247, 183, 205):
                    if Coinname.cell(1,1) == "Y" or Coinname.cell(1,1) is None :
                        for z in range(880, 930):  
                            if px[r, z] == (0, 255, 0): 
                                
                                main.Excel(self,Coinname,"X",2,deger)
                                
                                raise StopLookingForThings()
                    else : ## SAT ARA ##
                            if px[r+8, 206] == (255, 82,82):  # kırmızı ara
                                print("kırmızı buldum")
                                main.Excel(self, Coinname, "Y", 3, deger)
                                ### Al-Sat bot buraya - SAT emri.
                                raise StopLookingForThings()
    
        except:
            pass
    
    def Hepsi (self):
        coin = ["BTC","XRP"]
        for i in coin :
            main.AL_SAT_ARA(self,i)
    Gogogo = main()
    Gogogo.TRV_Giris()
    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(Gogogo.Hepsi)`
```

Comment: Your script is ending before the scheduler gets a chance to do anything.  I think what you need is `schedule.run_pending()` at the end, check the module documentation if that's not right.

Comment: When i run the code at the end with schedule.run_pending(), the code has finished agein with the same result, however it tries open a new chrome, and both the pages are closing at the same time less then a second.

Comment: Found the solution : i have add this code at the end and it works fine :
    'while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)'